# How to close navbar by closing anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know there are already similar questions out there but I am facing a weird issue. I am able to close the navbar by clicking outside it, but after that the navbar hamburger icon does not respond. This happens when I use
`window.addEventListener('click',()=>{});`.

Currently I am using

`document.getElementById("div-1").addEventListener("click", function () {});`,

but with this I am not able to close it by clicking outside my div. If I give an id to my body, I face the same issue as above. You will be able to close the navbar by clicking until where there is an a, as that is the "div-1", but not below them.

**open console and toggle hamburger icon, then try and close the navbar by clicking on the first div, the navbar checkbox does not return to false state**

tl;dr - How can I close my navbar by clicking outside it, and do it repeatedly.

Thank you!!

```js
$('#menu-btn').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById("div-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        // window.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        // $(document).click(function (event) {
        document.getElementById("menu-btn").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("myHeader").classList.remove("someClass");
      });

      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        document.getElementById("menu-btn").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("myHeader").classList.remove("someClass");
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
/* body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
} */


/* header */

.header {
  /* background-color: rgba(250, 246, 246, 0.6); */
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 10%; */
  z-index: 33;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-color: rgba(250, 246, 246, 0.4); */
  /* background-color: #fff; */
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  /* border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4; */
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  /* border-bottom: 2px white solid; */
  /* background-color: #f4f4f4; */
  /* color: grey; */
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .logo-down {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: white .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: white;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}


/* .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after,
.header .menu-icon .navicon{
  background-color: black;
} */

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.header {
  background-color: red;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  /* background-color: #000; */
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: black;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: black;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu li a {
  color: #333;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

.is-sticky {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 1s ease-in;
  margin-top: -1.2%;
}

.is-sticky-sm {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 1s ease-in;
  /* margin-top: -1.2%; */
}

.is-sticky-transparent {
  background-color: none;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
}

@media(min-width:565px) {
  .is-sticky-transparent {
    max-height: 10vh;
  }
}

.someClass {
  background-color: white;
  transform: .5s ease;
}

.hovertowhite::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  /* color: honeydew; */
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.hovertowhite:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.hovertowhite {
  /* color: white; */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hovertolight:hover {
  color: grey !important;
}


/* qwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww */

body {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header " id="myHeader">
  <a href="" class="logo" id="logo-manip">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon" id="menu-icon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu" id="menu-manip">
    <li><a href="#work" class="hovertowhite" id="nav-text1">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="hovertowhite" id="nav-text2">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="hovertowhite" id="nav-text3">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="hovertowhite" id="nav-text4">four</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div id="div-1">
  a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a
  <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> a <br> <br> a <br> a <br> a <br>
</div>




<script>
  $("#menu-btn").click(function(){
    console.log($(this)[0].checked);
});
if($("#menu-btn").checked){
  console.log('ll');
}
</script>




<script>
  $('#menu-btn').click(function() {
    $("#myHeader").toggleClass("someClass");
  });
</script>


<!-- NAVBAR STUFF -->
<script>
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

    const myBackground = document.getElementById('myHeader');
    const logo = document.getElementById('logo-manip');
    const menu = document.getElementById('menu-manip');
    const ham = document.getElementById('menu-icon');
    const texts1 = document.getElementById('nav-text1');
    const texts2 = document.getElementById('nav-text2');
    const texts3 = document.getElementById('nav-text3');
    const texts4 = document.getElementById('nav-text4');
    var styleElem1 = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
    var styleElem2 = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
    var styleElem3 = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 550) {
        myBackground.classList.add("is-sticky");
        logo.style.paddingTop = "8px";
        menu.style.paddingTop = "8px";
        texts1.classList.add("hovertolight");
        texts2.classList.add("hovertolight");
        texts3.classList.add("hovertolight");
        texts4.classList.add("hovertolight");
        texts1.style.color = "black";
        texts2.style.color = "black";
        texts3.style.color = "black";
        texts4.style.color = "black";
        styleElem1.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon {background: black;}";
        styleElem2.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:before {background: black;}";
        styleElem3.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:after {background: black;}";
      } else {
        myBackground.classList.remove("is-sticky");
        myBackground.classList.add("is-sticky-transparent");
        logo.style.marginTop = "0px";
        menu.style.marginTop = "0px";
        texts1.classList.remove("hovertolight");
        texts2.classList.remove("hovertolight");
        texts3.classList.remove("hovertolight");
        texts4.classList.remove("hovertolight");
        texts1.style.color = "white";
        texts2.style.color = "white";
        texts3.style.color = "white";
        texts4.style.color = "white";
        styleElem1.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon {background: white;}";
        styleElem2.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:before {background: white;}";
        styleElem3.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:after {background: white;}";
      }
    } else {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 230) {
        myBackground.classList.add("is-sticky-sm");
        logo.style.paddingTop = "8px";
        menu.style.bottom = "1px";
        texts1.style.color = "black";
        texts2.style.color = "black";
        texts3.style.color = "black";
        texts4.style.color = "black";
        styleElem1.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon {background: black;}";
        styleElem2.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:before {background: black;}";
        styleElem3.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:after {background: black;}";
      } else {
        myBackground.classList.remove("is-sticky-sm");
        myBackground.classList.add("is-sticky-transparent");
        logo.style.marginTop = "0px";
        menu.style.marginTop = "0px";
        styleElem1.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon {background: white;}";
        styleElem2.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:before {background: white;}";
        styleElem3.innerHTML = ".header .menu-icon .navicon:after {background: white;}";
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solutions for you:

1. You should just set height of your 'div-1' to 100vh. nothing more is required.
2. Alternatively you can wrap all your elements except the header to a container div and set its height to 100vh.

what happening is the height of your 'div-1' is not specified so it is only taking height of the elements inside it (the 'a' elements). rest of the area doesn't count in neither your 'div-1' element nor the body. so the javascript/jquery can't access that area.
because of that your eventlisteners are only working along with the height available for 'div-1'.
if you increase the height of the element then the javascript will be able to cover all that area for eventlistener.

that's my answer for you. Happy Designing.

--Edited part--
Add these lines to your second script (the script above 'NAVBAR Stuff')

```js
$("#parent").click(function(){ console.log($("#menu-btn")[0].checked = false); }); 

// it will look like this 

<script> 
$("#menu-btn").click(function(){ console.log($(this)[0].checked); }); 
$("#parent").click(function(){ console.log($("#menu-btn")[0].checked = false); });
if($("#menu-btn").checked){ console.log('ll'); } 
</script>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, the second suggestion worked. But I still don't get my console to say false when I click on the screen for my checkbox nav button. How can I achieve that as well?

Comment: Hey, nope I stell get true twice, no false register when closed by clicking outside :(

Comment: sorry for not explaining...the "#parent" is the wrapper div. replace it qith your wrapper div's id

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. I have a question even without this my code functionality was working perfectly, just that the check box was not showing the current status, how important is it to correct something like this? Does it even matter? If maybe the website is for production purpose?

Comment: You can use it check if everything is working correctly using console. otherwise as long as it works. its fine. BTW 
this line in above code is unreachable

if($("#menu-btn").checked){
      console.log('ll');
    }

because it only checks once when page loads and when the page loads the status of #menu-btn is always false because it's not checked at that time. So there is no point writing that line.

Comment: yes I removed that line. Thanks a lot for your help!!